# ZFS pool corrupted, shows /dev/sdb twice as disk used

Tags: raid, zfs

Woke up to a nasty surprise a couple of days ago to see that my zpool couldn't be imported. After discovering that sdb had faulted I assumed it was time to replace the drive, so I hot swapped it. After trying to figure out what to do next for a while zfs commands became non responsive, I assumed that maybe it was trying to repair itself, left it running for over a day, since zfs commands were still unresponsive I then force restarted the server. Now `zpool import` shows sdb twice...

```
pool       FAULTED  corrupted data
  raidz1-0  DEGRADED
    sda     ONLINE
    sdb     FAULTED  corrupted data
    sdb     ONLINE
    sde     ONLINE
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on, and what the best way is to repair the pool? I have not yet checked the drive that faulted.